# In this Symfony2 REST API tutorial, where is the 'posts' path part defined in the routes?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, routes

I have successfully completed [this tutorial](http://voryx.net/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-easy-way/) in order to learn how to implement a REST API using Symfony2.

In the tutorial, the path for each route of the actions in the generated REST controller are in the following format:

```
/api/posts/…
```

My question is; how and where is the 'posts' part of the path defined?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that this is defined by by the FOS\RestBundle using implicit resource name definition, it looks at the controller name and makes it plural (obviously has to be in singular form to begin with for it to work!).

In the tutorial the controller name is overridden via the @ResourceRoute("Post") annotation so this is used instead of the actual controller name.

I was able to figure this out based on information in the [FOSRestBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.md).

Answer (score 1):

It should be specified in your controller(if using annotations, otherwise in the routing file for your bundle) which has been automatically generated by the command line script below.

```
php app/console voryx:generate:rest --entity="AcmeDemoBundle:Post"
```

It seems to pluralise the name of the entity to generate routes. Post your controller and routing file from the bundle to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on Git:

```
api_posts:
    type:     rest
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/PostController.php"
    prefix: /api
```

..I'd say that they prefix their entities using the standard controller annotation:

```
/**
 * Post controller.
 *
 * @Route("/posts")
 */
class PostController extends Controller {
[..]
```